# Someone changed something on AWS Console I provisioned using Terraform. I don't want to override their change. What do I do?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I use terraform to provision parameters for AWS Systems Manager using `terraform apply`. In order to use the `aws_ssm_parameter`, you need to provide a value (i.e. a password or something). That's fine, but if someone changes or updates the parameter (as they can and should), then on my next terraform plan, it will detect this change and proceed to override the changed value again. I don't want Terraform to do that.

What specific commands can I use in Terraform to get the updated parameters and not override the changed parameter?

Would this be :

`terraform refresh && terraform plan`

Is that all?

Answer (score 1):

No, `terraform refresh` is not designed for such purpose, a good example of terraform refresh below

> For example, lets say your state file contains 3 EC2 instances with
>   instance ids of i-abc123, i-abc124, i-abc125 and then you delete
>   i-abc124 outside of Terraform. After running terraform refresh, a plan
>   would show that it needs to create the second instance while a destroy
>   plan would show that it only needs to destroy the first and third
>   instances (and not fail to destroy the missing second instance).

[what-does-terraform-refresh-really-do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42628660/what-does-terraform-refresh-really-do)

Better to keep do changes in terraform file and then apply changes in the terraform, by making such changes on infrastructure terraform will change such resources if it required or it will recreate based on the resource type.

For example, changing the instance type on remote and then run `terraform apply` it terminates the new instance and will create an instance with desired type that is in the Terraform state file.

There is a long way that is defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43950097/how-to-import-manual-changes-into-terraform-remote-state/43985365), but I will recommend to configure a pipeline that will take care of such changes instead of creating changes on the remote.

Comment: Do you have any reference to a pipeline implementation like you describe?

Comment: you can look into this gist, it is integrated with Jenkins, and all you need to run jenkins job for any changes, https://gist.github.com/Adiii717/8271a65d0c8469d4bbc9405f2850e8f7

Answer (score 1):

use the meta argument lifecycle ignore_changes to solve this problem.

Ex:

```
 resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  # ...

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      tags,
    ]
  }
}
```

This will ignore any tag changes made via the console. if you want this for all resources, you can use the keyword: **all** . I hope this helps.